# Chapter titles for book of article collections

Tags: pdftex, books

Is there a relatively straightforward method to make book of collected articles? (So, in a sense, each article becomes a chapter, the article name becomes the chapter title, etc., as in the screenshots from such a book.) If not, what are my options (preferably with pdfLaTeX)?

[image]

[image]

Perhaps, something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{The Best Writing on Mathematics 2019}
\author{Maria Pitici}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents%

\chaptertitle{Behind Monty Hall's Doors: Puzzle, Debate and Answer?}
\chapterauthor{John Tierney}
\chapteraffil{The New York Times}
\chapterdate{21 July, 1991}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the TugBoat [templates contains](https://tug.org/tugboat/location.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Sveinung -- Each TUGboat item is processed separately and they are "stitched together" later by a non-TeX process.  (TUGboat items are a mix of plain TeX, LaTeX, some ConTeXt, and even occasionally some non-TeX pages.  Even within consecutive LaTeX items, they often require incompatible packages.)